# Is there any way to modify this function so that it removes the previous element in the array - C

Tags: c, arrays, list

So I've been given the task of modifying a previous code (which simulates a deck of card) to do it more accuarely by having the cards in the array be removed after they are drawn.

I know there are ways to do this using linked list but I'm still new to using linked list and would like so help because I'm on a strict timeline not to mention that doing it how i've been taught I'd have to completely change my code which uses arrays, to structs and pointers which would cost time I don't have.

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
    int numCards = 10;
    int i; 
    int hand[numCards];
    int card;
    for(i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
    {
        card = deck[i];     
        hand[i] = card;     
        cards(card); 
    }
}
```

This is the current fucuntion that i need to modify so that when a card is added to hand[i] the card is removed from deck[i] so i don't get repeats.

cards is a function that prints the cards and can be ignore

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 52

enum faces{Ace = 0, Jack = 10, Queen, King};
char * facecheck(int d); 
void shuffle( int deck[]);
void draw(int deck[SIZE]); 
void cards(int hand); 
int i;
int main() 
{ 
    int deck[SIZE], i, n;
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"
    };


    srand( time( NULL ) ) ;

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = i;
    };

    shuffle(deck);
    draw(deck);
    shuffle(deck); 
    draw(deck);



    return 0; 
}
```

This is the current main function, shuffle does as you would think and draw is the function I need to modify because, even though it randomly cycles through cards, if run enough two cards can appear in the same hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special card (-1) that indicates deletion. Hence:

```
card = deck[i];     
hand[i] = card;
deck[i] = -1; // deleted  
cards(card);
```

Comment: what do you add a 'special card'

Comment: The special card (-1) can be used to check if the card exists or has been deleted. The value in deck[i] will never be -1 unless it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a remove function which moves all next elements to the previous index and sets the last index to `-1`.

Though, it is not possible to **really** remove an element from an array in C, because it has a static allocated size which can not be modified, all you can do is something like this.

```
void remove_from_array(int index, int* array, int size)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < size)
      {
        if (i >= index && i == (size - 1))
          array[i] = -1;
        else if (i >= index)
          array[i] = array[i + 1];
        i++;
      }
}

remove_from_array(i, deck, SIZE);
```

Comment: How would i set up the 'index' would that just be array[i]? cause I have the compiler fill in all the values?